# Jenkins Checking out a fresh workspace

Tags: svn, hudson, jenkins

I am getting up and running with Jenkins and every time my build runs, it checks out a new version of the source from subversion even though I have the check out strategy set to use 'svn update' as much as possible.  Here is the actual message:

> Checking out a fresh workspace because
>   the workspace is not
>   https://wks-alaytin.1EDI.1EDIWeb.com/svn/1EDISource/IC.SAP/trunk
>
> Cleaning workspace C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\EDI IC SAP
>   R3\workspace
>
> Checking out
>   https://wks-alaytin.1EDI.1EDIWeb.com/svn/1EDISource/IC.SAP/trunk
>   ...

Does anyone know why it is checking out a fresh workspace each time?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't have the workspace cleanup configured, right?

Comment: No, I don't have workspace cleanup configured.

Comment: I had a similar problem....  but it was because the name of the server in my SVN path was in CAPS.  I changed it to lower case and it worked....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my research I found that this is a bug in the SVN plugin.  Here is the bug:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10222

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link provided the solution to my problem with 2 checkouts for one job.